# CSS: Customizing Transforms

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to customize transforms and transitions **in CSS**?  For example, in this Jsfiddle, I'd like to for the first 2 seconds, transform 110 degrees, then for 4 seconds, transform 200 degrees.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/b5zun436/

```css
.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
    transform: rotate(110deg);
}
```

```html
<p>CSS question: IS there a way to customize the transform? (i.e., transform box to 110 deg, duration 2 seconds and then transform box another 180 degrees, duration 5 seconds. </p>
    <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use a CSS animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use key-frame animation for this, that's why it is called as **key frame** animation, where you define it frame by frame.

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
    0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
    33.3% { -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg); transform: rotate(110deg); }
    100%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(200deg); transform: rotate(200deg); }
}
```

Comment: @Snorlax Hope this helped. Wow, I am surprised you didn't know about this. `:)`

Comment: @ManojKumar No no, no bad words. `:P`